# CSS3 transition on a background image

Tags: html, css, background, css-transitions

I want to do an CSS3 transform: rotate(360deg); in a transition 1s; 
on a background image instead of a seperate image(element)..
Is this possible? I have searched the hell out of Google but no succes!
What I am trying to achieve is something like:

```
#footerLogo { 
  background: url('ster.png'), 
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s,
  transition: transform 1s,
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s,
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  background-position: #outlinedtotheleft;
}
#footerLogo:hover {
  background: transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

I hope this is possible! I know it is easily doable in JS (jQuery) with:

```
$('#something').hover(function(){morecodehere});
```

...but I want to know if it is possible with only CSS(3)

HTML:

```
<div id="footerLogo">
  <img src="carenza.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: When adding code blocks next time, just indent the whole block by 4+ spaces to preserve indentation.  Use backticks for inline code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure you can, try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="planet">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#planet { 
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: transparent url(http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nx11/Internet%20-%20Real.png) no-repeat center center;
}

#planet {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration:2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/YqdJb/1/)

Comment: almost, but it only has to transition on a mouseover and the div contains 1 another IMG. imagine; you have a little star image (seperate but part of an original logo) and the rest of that logo ("Some Name") beside of it. If i hover over the div (one of both images) then only the star rotates. With only CSS3.. 

Still nice example though :-) !

Comment: now I'm trying to edit your code to achieve the effect that the star will rotate back (to beginning point) if your mouse is not hovering anymore

Comment: With css3 there are no ways that you can go about it (at least none that i'm aware off). Hover states are pretty linear and don't allow you to transition between on-hover and off-hover, you can use javascript for that.

Comment: yes you can solve the problem with JS but the challenge is to do it in CSS3 ;).. I have achieved it before; to make transition go back with an 'onmouseout' (as you may call it ;) but I am helped alot already and the main question is answered (i guess?). I think i cannot also ask this in the same thread.

Comment: Well, i think it is simple to pull off using any other type of other transformation, like padding for example, you can manipulate it to grow the padding by 10px on :hover state and to lower the padding on :active state, but something as abstract as rotation i dont think that level of specificity is doable with just css. Again, i could be wrong, i see something new in CSS3 everyday.

Comment: Did a little bit more testing and made the demo a bit more fluid, you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/YqdJb/3/  ... i omitted the vendor prefixes for firefox for testing so test in Chrome, you can add those later.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can apply a transform to the background image itself (separately from the div.) However, you can rotate the whole div, including using a transition to animate it ([here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/Y472Y/).)

It might help if you could describe the exact effect you want to achieve?

Code:

```
#footerlogo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixum.com/200/200);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

#footerlogo:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: unprefixed css declaration should be always last! you want to use standard implementation once its ready and not overwrite it by browser specific ones what might be left broken.

Comment: @gondo In 2011, I doubt anyone was thinking that far ahead :) I'll change the order.